# Custom ProgressBar not spinning, when open from onResume()

Tags: android

I have a `custom progress bar` in my app. When I open my app, this `Custom ProgressBar` works well, but in some situations where my app *calls itself*, the `onCreate()` event does not called.

The app starts from an `onResume()` event. I have created a function to open the progress bar that is called in the `onResume()` event. The problem is that the `custom Progress Bar` gets opened but does not start `SPINNING`, and it is dismissed after the task is completed. It therefor appears as if the application is hanging.

Are there any solution for this?

Comment: try start spinning the spinner if the custom spinner is alive

Comment: give me custom Progress Bar xml code